# Conversion of strings to numbers

Tags: r, string

Hello I'm looking for a way to turn user inputted strings into matrices for example: 28 = SPACE, 27 = ?, 26 = 0, 25 = A, 24=B 23=C 22=D 21=E 20=F 19=G 18=H
17=I 16=J 15=K 14=L 13=M 12=N 11=O 10=P 9=Q 8=R 7=S 6=T 5=U 4=V 3=W 2=X 1=Y 0=Z

```
"HI HOW ARE YOU?" -> "[18 17 28 18 11][3 28 25 8 21][28 1 11 5 27]"
```

wherein each letter/symbol of the string is converted to a numerical value (special attention to spacebar I really don't know how to turn space into numbers). I'll be using these matrices to make a cryptograph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `utf8ToInt`

```
x <- "HI HOW ARE YOU?"
```

We need `pmin` to get your condition `28 = SPACE` right.

```
pmin(abs(utf8ToInt("HI HOW ARE YOU?") - utf8ToInt("Z")), 28)
# [1] 18 17 28 18 11  3 28 25  8 21 28  1 11  5 27
```

---

From `?utf8ToInt` :

> Conversion of UTF-8 encoded character vectors to and from integer vectors representing a UTF-32 encoding.

First step is

```
utf8ToInt("HI HOW ARE YOU?")
[1] 72 73 32 72 79 87 32 65 82 69 32 89 79 85 63
```

from which we substract `utf8ToInt("Z")`, i.e. `90` because you wrote `0=Z`.

Call `abs` on the result to get positive numbers.

```
abs(utf8ToInt("HI HOW ARE YOU?") - utf8ToInt("Z"))
# [1] 18 17 58 18 11  3 58 25  8 21 58  1 11  5 27
```

The last piece is your condition `28 = SPACE`, which is where `pmin` helps you out.